# HttpClient post record, status OK but record is not created and empty response

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpclient, integration

I have a plugin using HttpClient which is supposed to create a record in external ERP database. I am sending a request, everything on my side is ok, I receive a status OK but response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() is empty. In ERP database record is not created. Code below

```
      public class OnPostCreate : BaseClass
{
    private static Uri baseAdress = new Uri("http://adress/ws/Methodname.json?raw=");
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public static string trace = "";
    public override void ExecutePlugin()
    {
        Account account = ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Account>();
        Account getAcc = dataContext.AccountSet.Where(p => p.Id == account.Id)
            .Select(p => new Account()
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                jar_id = p.jar_id,
                jar_field1= p.jar_field1,
                jar_field2= p.jar_field2,
                jar_field3= p.jar_field3,
                jar_field4= p.jar_field4
            })
            .SingleOrDefault();      

        if (getAcc == null) return;

        ModelClass model = CreateModel(getAcc);
        string content = GetContent(model);

        Account acc = new Account
        {
            Description = baseAdress + content,
            Id = getAcc.Id
        };
        service.Update(acc);

        RunAsync(content, tracingService).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        tracingService.Trace(trace);
    }

    private static async Task RunAsync(string content, ITracingService tracingService)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = baseAdress;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        try
        {
            await SendRequest(HttpMethod.Post, content);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message + e.InnerException + e.InnerException.InnerException);
        }
    }

    private static async Task SendRequest(HttpMethod method, string query)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, query);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string responsetext = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        trace += "Code:" + response.StatusCode.ToString();
        trace += "/n Response: " + responsetext;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    private ModelClass CreateModel(Account account) => new ModelClass()
    {
        Id = account.jar_id,
        field4= account.jar_field4,
       field1 = Convert.ToInt32(account.jar_field1 ),
        field2= Convert.ToInt32(account.jar_field2),
        field3= account.jar_field3
    };

    private string GetContent(ClassModel model) => $"<RequestData>" +
                        $"<Id>{model.Id}</Id>" +
                        $"<field1>{model.field1}</field1>" +
                        $"<field2>{model.field2}</field2>" +
                        $"<field3>{model.field3}</field3>" +
                        $"<field4>{model.field4}</field4>" +
                        $"</RequestData>";
}
```

Please help! Any suggestions why on my side everything seems to be OK (but response is empty??) and on the other side there is no even a mark of request.

I pasted the request url to postman and at first attempt i got no response, second one: 503 error Object reference not set to an instance of an object at DataService.Modules.Json.JsonHandler.Process(HttpListenerContext context) at DataService.Common.HttpServer.BeginGetContextCompleted(IAsyncResult result)

Regards

Comment: Sounds like the webservice did not create any response text.  Do you get text back if you use something like postman to test?

Comment: Can you reproduce behavior with Postman, for example?

Comment: It is up to the implementation of a service to return useful status codes. Just because you get 200 OK doesn't necessarily mean there wasn't a problem. It could mean the service is using poor API etiquette or it deemed the operation successful and you have a different interpretation of success.

Comment: i pasted the request url to postman and at first attempt i got no response, second one: 503 error Object reference not set to an instance of an object  at DataService.Modules.Json.JsonHandler.Process(HttpListenerContext context)
   at DataService.Common.HttpServer.BeginGetContextCompleted(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody here can guess/debug your communication with "some service"/"external ERP.." API/endpoint....